# telepathy-glib send a XMPP message

Tags: c, linux, xmpp, glib, gnome-shell

Using [GNOME Online Accounts API](https://developer.gnome.org/goa/stable/) I'm getting a [TelepathyGLibAccount](http://valadoc.org/#!api=telepathy-glib/TelepathyGLib.Account) object and then the [Connection](http://valadoc.org/#!api=telepathy-glib/TelepathyGLib.Connection) used in, but I can't find any documentation/example how to send a XMPP message (or at least a message to other client). Any ideas?